# My ASP.NET Core app does not appear on Centos server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I published my ASP.NET Core project to my server and it's running on the server.
But when I open my domain on browser it shows Centos welcome page not my project.

What's the problem ?

[Commands image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Juusd.jpg)

[Result page image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJqoO.jpg)

Comment: Did you open the web site in your browser on port 5000 or 5001?

Comment: As mentioned above , try to open the port on which your app is running (http://localhost:5001)

Answer (score 0):

you must install and config Nginx to run your app for public User its like IIS on windows server see:
https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-deploy-a-net-core-web-application-on-centos-7

Comment: Hello 
I already Installed nginx on my server but it doesn't work

Comment: do you config it too? it's a tricky job you must find where is the problem began exactly